# Transfer Joomla website to other server Akeeba

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

I need to transfer a website from a server to another. PHP version 5.3 and joomla 3.8 so Akeeba is not compatible . Is there a similar tool? Because I tried it manually by moving the files and dumping the sql but didn't worked

Comment: You can download v4.7.7 of akeeba Backup which is compatible with PHP 5.3: https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup/4-7-7.html

Comment: @Lodder its not compatible with joomla 3.8 though

Comment: It may be though, perhaps give it a test

Comment: @Lodder I did with no luck...

Comment: Is there no way to update the PHP version on your current host?

Comment: @Lodder if I update an extension wont work

Comment: So if you update to PHP 5.4, you're saying your extensions won't work? Have you tried seeing if there are any updates for your extensions?

Comment: No there aren't... Thats why I downgraded to 5.3

Comment: You may want to start considering looking for alternative extensions then. Downgrading to PHP 5.3 is a **very** bad move.

Comment: Yeap I know that. I am currently building a new website. But I need this one until the newest is done

Comment: So temporarily update to PHP 5.4+, take a backup, revert the PHP version, then install the backup on your new host. You can then disable the extension that isn't compatible with PHP 5.4+ on your new server

Comment: It should be also possible to move the website with the "classic way"... Meaning, zipping everything in the public_html and getting a mysql dump, using the tools available in your hosting panel. You may have some issues if the hosting is Godaddy Classic, which by personal experience is usually timing out when trying to zip the contents of the website. But in any case, you can ask your hosting provider for support on getting a complete backup of your root folder and your databases.

Answer (score 5):

It should be also possible to move the website with the "classic way"... Meaning, zipping everything in the public_html and getting a mysql dump, using the tools available in your hosting panel.

You may have some issues if the hosting is Godaddy Classic Hosting, which by personal experience, is usually timing out when trying to zip the contents of a Joomla site, especially if there are many files. But in any case, you can ask your hosting provider for support on getting a complete backup of your root folder and your databases.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ssh access on both servers, you can first dump the database (using `mysql >`), zip the filesystem (using `zip -r`), copy both to the other server (using `scp`), re-import the database (using `mysql <`), and finally unzip the filesystem (using `unzip`).